# Using Python to field calculate Lat/Long with decimal degrees rather than meters

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, latitude-longitude

The below is a snippet of a python script that I am writing that basically adds two fields - Latitude and Longitude, then calculates them. I could use the Add XY Tool which gets me to the same point. The way that I did it with the expression3 and expression4 variables should work but doesn't. The projection is WGS 84 the script works fully from start to finish. The columns are calculated in meters rather than decimal degrees which is what is needed for the project.

Any thoughts?

```
... 
... 
... 

## Add Lat/Long Fields 
inFeature = "Point_Feature_Class" 
fieldName1 = "Latitude" 
fieldName2 = "Longitude" 
fieldType = "DOUBLE" 
arcpy.AddField_management(inFeature, fieldName1, fieldType) 
arcpy.AddField_management(inFeature, fieldName2, fieldType) 

## Execute CalculateField of Lat/Long Fields 
expression1 = "{0}".format("!SHAPE.extent.XMax!") 
expression2 = "{0}".format("!SHAPE.extent.YMax!") 
#expression3 = "{0}".format("!SHAPE.extent@decimaldegrees!") 
#expression4 = "{0}".format("!SHAPE.extent@decimaldegrees!") 

arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeature, fieldName1, expression1, "PYTHON_9.3") 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeature, fieldName2, expression2, "PYTHON_9.3") 
#arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeature, fieldName1, expression3, "PYTHON_9.3") 
#arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeature, fieldName2, expression4, "PYTHON_9.3")

... 
... 
...
```

Answer (score 10):

As stated in the [tool documentation for Calculate Field](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm):

> Python expressions can use the geometry `area` and `length` properties with an areal or linear unit to convert the value to a different unit of measure (for example, `!shape.length@kilometers!`)

These expressions are **not usable with points** or individual coordinates. Fortunately, you can use other properties and methods of the [`pointGeometry`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/pointgeometry.htm) and [`point`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/point.htm) classes to get your desired result.

Since your data is already in a geographic coordinate system, the following will return latitude and longitude values of your points. (Technically this returns the coordinates of the first part of each point, but that's only relevant if you are using [`MultiPoint`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/multipoint.htm) geometry).

```
!SHAPE!.firstPoint.X #Longitude
!SHAPE!.firstPoint.Y #Latitude
```

If your data were in a different coordinate system, the following field calculator expressions convert each point to a `PointGeometry` object and then use the `projectAs` to project each point to the WGS84 geographic coordinate system before getting the coordinates. If your data has a datum other than WGS84, you should use the appropriate [`SpatialReference`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/spatialreference.htm) object constructed using the name or [well-known ID of the datum](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/pdf/geographic_coordinate_systems.pdf).

```
arcpy.PointGeometry(!Shape!.firstPoint,!Shape!.spatialReference).projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)).firstPoint.X
arcpy.PointGeometry(!Shape!.firstPoint,!Shape!.spatialReference).projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)).firstPoint.X
```

I don't know why it's necessary to create the `PointGeometry` object instead of just running `projectAs` on `!SHAPE!`. On ArcMap 10.3 the `!SHAPE!` object is `<type 'geoprocessing describe geometry object'>` while the `PointGeometry` is `<class 'arcpy.arcobjects.geometries.PointGeometry'>` in ArcMap 10.3. This is not necessary when using cursors in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out with a work around. I added the Lat/Long Fields and then us Convert Coordinate Notation. That generated a new feature class with two new fields: DDLat and DDLon. That got me what I needed even though I had to add a couple additional steps. The output was 076.###W, 37.####N as opposed to what I wanted which was (-76.###, 37.####) so I am adding steps now to recalculate the fields to make them into that format and delete the old file etc...

The specific steps that I had to do were:

```
## Field Calculate
input_FeatureClass = "wPM_Points_Converted"
expression3 = "{0}".format("!DDLat![:-1]") 
expression4 = "{0}".format("!DDLon![1:-1]")
expression5 = "{0}".format("- !Longitude!")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(input_FeatureClass, "Latitude", expression3, "PYTHON_9.3")
print "Latitude Field Calculation Complete"
arcpy.CalculateField_management(input_FeatureClass, "Longitude", expression4, "PYTHON_9.3")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(input_FeatureClass, "Longitude", expression5, "PYTHON_9.3")
print "Longitude Field Calculation Complete"

## Delete fields that were created from Coordinate Notation
arcpy.DeleteField_management(input_FeatureClass,  ["DDLat", "DDLon"])
print "Deleted fields that were created from Coordinate Notation"
```