# Calculating centroids in decimal degrees using ArcPy without reprojecting vector data?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, centroids

I have vector data not in geographical coordinate system (i.e. not in WGS 1984).

How to calculate object's centroids using `arcpy` without reprojecting the data itself?

I have tried to do this but **it doesn't work** (centroids are in meters):

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature, fieldName, "!SHAPE.CENTROID.X!","PYTHON_9.3")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature, fieldName, "!SHAPE.CENTROID.Y!","PYTHON_9.3")

arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature, fieldName, "!SHAPE.CENTROID@DECIMALDEGREES!.split()[0]", "PYTHON") 
arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature, fieldName, "!SHAPE.CENTROID@DECIMALDEGREES!.split()[1]", "PYTHON")
```

Comment: Why ask and then answer your own question 1 min later

Comment: I just wasted a lot of time to find the answer (about 2 hours). This can save a lot of time to the other people. Besides 3 years ago i resolve this problem and forgot how i did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `arcpy.CalculateField_management`with following expressions:

For **x** coordinates:

```
expression = 'arcpy.PointGeometry(!Shape!.centroid,!Shape!.spatialReference).projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)).centroid.X'
arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature, fieldName, expression,"PYTHON_9.3")
```

For **y** coordinates:

```
expression = 'arcpy.PointGeometry(!Shape!.centroid,!Shape!.spatialReference).projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)).centroid.Y'
arcpy.CalculateField_management(feature, fieldName, expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: This answer is based on http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/155477/35561